# Visual Studio/Resharper: Automatically create string continaing all method parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

From time to time I need to log/trace the parameters of a method. Does anybody know if Visual Studio or Resharper has the ability to auto-generate a string like:

```
$"{nameof(method)}: {nameof(param1)}={param1}, {nameof(param2)}={param2}"
```

So it's kind of a "macro" (-> I know that Resharper can automatically generate a `ToString` dumping all object properties, so it should be possible). Can somebody give me a hint how to generate such kind of string via Visual Studio or Resharper.

Thanks.